# How to check and kill cron job if particular cron running using shell script

Tags: bash, cron

I have two cron jobs for importing image process into Database and scheduled that cron runs per two days once at server time 1 hour 2min. I need to check if the cron runs or not using shell script and kill that cron if the runs that cron already or after two days. Can you anybody guide me?

Example:

```
2 1 */2 * *  cd /var/www/railsapp/book_app_v2 && /usr/local/bin/rake RAILS_ENV=production db:load_java_photo 2>&1 >> /var/www/railsapp/book_app/log/cron_book_photo.log
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you right, you want to prevent cron overruns. Check out [hatools](http://www.fatalmind.com/software/hatools/), which addresses exactly that issue.

> **halockrun** provides a simple and reliable way to implement a locking in shell scripts. A typical usage for halockrun is to prevent
>   cronjobs to run simultanously. halockrun's implementation makes it
>   very resilient to all kind of stale locks.
>
> **hatimerun** provides a time-out mechanism that can be used from shell scripts. hatimerun can set multiple actions--signals to be
>   sent--on multiple timeouts.